# How to count number of fields by specific column in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the schema with the tables :

Products

[image]

And Family

[image]

How can I get the number of products of each family_code ?

This :

```
SELECT count(family_code)
FROM products;
```

returns the number of `family_code` record in the Products table ,how can I alter that
to find each family_code with its number of products ?

Thanks

For instance

[image]

1234 has 2

2345 has 1

12345 has 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By starting with the family table and LEFT JOINing to the products table, this will list all family codes, regardless if they are in the product table or not (i.e., it will list families that have no products)

```
SELECT f.family_code,f.family_name, COUNT(p.prod_id) AS number_of_products
FROM family AS f
LEFT JOIN products AS p
 ON f.family_code = p.family_code
GROUP BY f.family_code, family_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(*)` grouped by `family_code`:

```
select family_code, count(*) product_count
from products
group by family_code
```